# Decompressing .snappy.parquet file

Tags: compression, parquet, snappy

I am trying to inflate a `.snappy.parquet` file, but i only find tools to parse it and output the parsed data.

I would like to to create a `.parquet` file that i can give to another program.

Looked into `python parquet-tools`, and `java parquet-tools`, but didn't find that options there.

Thanks.